# Get properties of an object associated with a row in a section of a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, select, row, datasource, sections

So, I have this datasource, an NSArray consisting of custom objects.

I display the source in a UITableView. Based upon the objects' properties, the tableview is divided into sections.

Somehow, I'm not able to figure out, how to get the correct object, when a user selects a row.

I need to find the selected object, to modify its properties, after which I can rebuild the UITableView.

I'm sure it's something simple. Please help me!

Comment: Everything anybody needs to know in order to help will be contained in the three datasource methods: numberOfSections, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Paste those in, and you'll get help within seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use delegate function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and then from it's argument `indexPath` take your custom object like `dataSource[indexPath.row]`. For now it's hard to tell you did not mention how you store these objects.

Comment: That returns just the row WITHIN the section and the section. I don't understand how I can use that information to get the associated object from the datasource

Comment: It depend how you store them inside your datasource. Other way is to for certain cell when you are drawing them just add a field to custom cell class with your datasource type and assign it to it then you can grab this object from cell itself.

Comment: You can also make a dict from your dataSource and hold it like [SectionRow, object] then you can get it from didSelect method i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that your datasource is something like this:

```
self.dogs = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Affenpinscher",@"Afghan Hound",@"Alaskan Malamute", nil];
```

You can access a specific value from the NSArray with the indexPath.row parameter of one delegate method of the UITableView:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *dogDreed = [self.dogs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Dreed of dog selected: %@", dogDreed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I ended up doing the following (simplified):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    myObject *theObject = [arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tag = theObject;
    return cell;

}
```

and then, in order to retrieve it, I do:

```
// (called from a UITableView delegate)

-(void)identifyObject:(id)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    int hash = selectedCell.tag;
    NSPredicate *cellHashFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hash == %i", hash];
    myObject *theEvent = [arrayOfObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:cellHashFilter][0];

   //doing some stuff here
    [self refreshTable];
}
```